# Intent Error in Android Studio (workout app)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

For my school project, I'm currently doing simple workout app. But I'm stuck on countdown timer because app keeps crashing. First, there are some welcome screens; and then, you proceed to make your own workout (choose exercises, rest and number of rounds). It works fine, and it even work to get all these variables into next class using Intent. Here is button NEXT code:

```
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(CustomWorkout.this, GetReady.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("all_exercises", Exercises); //arraylist of exercises
            myIntent.putExtra("total_rounds", total_rounds); //number of rounds
            myIntent.putExtra("total_rest", total_rest); //rest time
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

As you can see above, I then call **GetReady()** class which is simple 5 second countdown timer to prepare yourself for first exercise. **GetReady** looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.getready);

    getReady();
}


public void getReady(){
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    cTimer= new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            startActivity(new Intent(GetReady.this, Exercises.class));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

And now it comes to error (and crashing of the app). On finish of countdown I call **Exercise()** class (which is screen with name of current exercise and button done -> on click you start countdown timer again). Code:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    all_exercises = (ArrayList<String>) i.getSerializableExtra("all_exercises"); //getting exercises from Intent set in first class
    rounds=(int)i.getSerializableExtra("total_rounds");
    exercise_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise_name);
    exercise_name.setText(all_exercises.get(0));

    final Button done=(Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(Exercises.this, Countdown.class); //starting Countdown
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

GetReady timer countdowns normally and then the crash happens. If I set in first class that button NEXT should call Exercises class instead of GetReady it doesn't crash (but it crashes on Countdown class instead).

Crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.msimonic.worldofworkout, PID: 8968
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.msimonic.worldofworkout/com.msimonic.worldofworkout.Exercises}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
   at com.msimonic.worldofworkout.Exercises.onCreate(Exercises.java:39)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

Comment: If it crashes then please share the stack trace from Logcat

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to app programming. Edited original post.

Comment: Looks like you get a NullPointerException because you forgot to pass on the data from the Intent in GetReady, so getIntent() in Exercises has no extras

Comment: So I need to declare intent in GetReady class, get variables and put them forward to Exercises (and do that also in Exercises for forwarding to Countdown class)? I thought that Intent was something like session variable in php

Comment: Basically yes, and for me an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) is more like an envelope for Android's in-system communication. It may contain very different pieces of information, depending on what you want to do with it

Comment: I tried to do it as you said but I keep getting same error. First in onCreate I collected all variables and then before starting new activity (on countdown finish) I .putExtra all of them. Must I name all intents the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass on the data in *GetReady* so you can access them in *Exercises*. In order to write less code, I put them into a `Bundle` and simply transfer this `Bundle`:

In the `OnClickListener`:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CustomWorkout.this, GetReady.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("all_exercises", Exercises); //arraylist of exercises

        b.putInt("total_rounds", total_rounds); //number of rounds
        b.putInt("total_rest", total_rest); //rest time
        myIntent.putExtra("myData", b);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

In *GetReady.java*:

```
public void getReady(){
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    cTimer= new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Bundle b = GetReady.this.getIntent().getBundleExtra("myData");
            Intent myNextIntent = new Intent(GetReady.this, Exercises.class);
            myNextIntent.putExtra("myDataFromGetReady", b); 
            startActivity(myNextIntent);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

In *Excercises.java*:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getBundleExtra("myDataFromGetReady"); 

// now get the data from the Bundle: 
all_exercises = (ArrayList<String>) b.getSerializable("all_exercises"); 
rounds= b.getInt("total_rounds", -1);

exercise_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exercise_name);
exercise_name.setText(all_exercises.get(0));

final Button done=(Button) findViewById(R.id.done);

// ... and so on ...
```